# Unwanted Line at page beginning

Tags: thesis

I can't figure out why this line comes into my page. I am doing just

```
\input{frontmatter/abstract}
```

to include a page defined in the abstract.tex file, yet my page shows a line :

[image]

How to remove this line ? I am using the document class

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir}
```

The main file is:

```
    %\title{University of Bristol Thesis Template}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}        % Warns for incorrect (obsolete) LaTeX usage

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir} %add 'draft' to turn draft option on (see below)
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
%
% Adding metadata:
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Author's name)
   /Title (PhD Thesis)
   /Keywords (One; Two;Three)
   /CreationDate (D:\pdfdate)
}
\fi
% When draft option is on. 
\ifdraftdoc 
    \usepackage{draftwatermark}             %Sets watermarks up.
    \SetWatermarkScale{0.3}
    \SetWatermarkText{\bf Draft: \today}
\fi
%
% Declare figure/table as a subfloat.
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
% Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% Text should be in double or 1.5 line spacing, and font size should be
% chosen to ensure clarity and legibility for the main text and for any
% quotations and footnotes. Margins should allow for eventual hard binding.
%
% Note: This is automatically set by memoir class. Nevertheless \OnehalfSpacing 
% enables double spacing but leaves single spaced for captions for instance. 
\OnehalfSpacing 
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
% Chapter style (taken and slightly modified from Lars Madsen Memoir Chapter 
% Styles document
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier}
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
            \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}
%
% UoB guidelines:
%
% The pages should be numbered consecutively at the bottom centre of the
% page.
\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}
%
% Oscar's command (it works):
% Fills blank pages until next odd-numbered page. Used to emulate single-sided
% frontmatter. This will work for title, abstract and declaration. Though the
% contents sections will each start on an odd-numbered page they will
% spill over onto the even-numbered pages if extending beyond one page
% (hopefully, this is ok).
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
%
%
% Creates indexes for Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables and Index
\makeindex
% \printglossaries below creates a list of abbreviations. \gls and related
% commands are then used throughout the text, so that latex can automatically
% keep track of which abbreviations have already been defined in the text.
%
% The import command enables each chapter tex file to use relative paths when
% accessing supplementary files. For example, to include
% chapters/brewing/images/figure1.png from chapters/brewing/brewing.tex we can
% use
% \includegraphics{images/figure1}
% instead of
% \includegraphics{chapters/brewing/images/figure1}
\usepackage{import}

% Add other packages needed for chapters here. For example:
\usepackage{lipsum}                 %Needed to create dummy text
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   %Calls Amer. Math. Soc. (AMS) fonts
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}            %Writes maths centred down
\usepackage{stmaryrd}                   %New AMS symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}                    %Calls AMS symbols
\usepackage{amsthm}                 %Calls AMS theorem environment
\usepackage{newlfont}                   %Helpful package for fonts and symbols
\usepackage{layouts}                    %Layout diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}                   %Calls figure environment
\usepackage{longtable,rotating}         %Long tab environments including rotation. 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}         %Needed to encode non-english characters 
                                    %directly for mac
\usepackage{colortbl}                   %Makes coloured tables
\usepackage{wasysym}                    %More math symbols
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                   %Even more math symbols
\usepackage{float}                      %Helps to place figures, tables, etc. 
\usepackage{verbatim}                   %Permits pre-formated text insertion
\usepackage{upgreek }                   %Calls other kind of greek alphabet
\usepackage{latexsym}                   %Extra symbols
\usepackage[square,numbers,
             sort&compress]{natbib}     %Calls bibliography commands 
\usepackage{url}                        %Supports url commands
\usepackage{etex}                       %eTeXÕs extended support for counters
\usepackage{fixltx2e}                   %Eliminates some in felicities of the 
                                    %original LaTeX kernel
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}     %For languages characters and hyphenation
\usepackage{color}                                  %Creates coloured text and background
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
             allcolors=black]{hyperref}              %Creates hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{memhfixc}                   %Must be used on memoir document 
                                    %class after hyperref
\usepackage{enumerate}                  %For enumeration counter
\usepackage{footnote}                   %For footnotes
\usepackage{microtype}                  %Makes pdf look better.
\usepackage{rotfloat}                   %For rotating and float environments as tables, 
                                    %figures, etc. 
\usepackage{alltt}                      %LaTeX commands are not disabled in 
                                    %verbatim-like environment
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}          %PGF/TikZ is a tandem of languages for producing vector graphics from a 
\usepackage{tikz}                       %geometric/algebraic description.
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}               %To use diverse features from tikz      
%                           
%Reduce widows  (the last line of a paragraph at the start of a page) and orphans 
% (the first line of paragraph at the end of a page)
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000
%
% New command definitions for my thesis
%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\noindent{\small{\bf Keywords:} #1}} %Defines keywords small section
\newcommand{\parcial}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}                             %Defines a partial operator
\newcommand{\vectorr}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}                                                        %Defines a bold vector
\newcommand{\vecol}[2]{\left(                                                                         %Defines a column vector
    \begin{array}{c} 
        \displaystyle#1 \\
        \displaystyle#2
    \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\mados}[4]{\left(                                                                       %Defines a 2x2 matrix
    \begin{array}{cc}
        \displaystyle#1 &\displaystyle #2 \\
        \displaystyle#3 & \displaystyle#4
    \end{array}\right)}
\newcommand{\pgftextcircled}[1]{                                                                    %Defines encircled text
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \dimen0\wd0%
    \divide\dimen0 by 2%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base)]%
        \useasboundingbox (-\the\dimen0,0pt) rectangle (\the\dimen0,1pt);
        \node[circle,draw,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0.1ex] (a) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\range}[1]{\textnormal{range }#1}                                             %Defines range operator
\newcommand{\innerp}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}                                 %Defines inner product
\newcommand{\prom}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}                                         %Defines average operator
\newcommand{\tra}[1]{\textnormal{tra} \: #1}                                                       %Defines trace operator
\newcommand{\sign}[1]{\textnormal{sign\,}#1}                                                   %Defines sign operator
\newcommand{\sech}[1]{\textnormal{sech} #1}                                                  %Defines sech
\newcommand{\diag}[1]{\textnormal{diag} #1}                                                    %Defines diag operator
\newcommand{\arcsech}[1]{\textnormal{arcsech} #1}                                       %Defines arcsech
\newcommand{\arctanh}[1]{\textnormal{arctanh} #1}                                         %Defines arctanh
%Change tombstone symbol
\newcommand{\blackged}{\hfill$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\whiteged}{\hfill$\square$}
\newcounter{proofcount}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname.]{\par
 \ifnum \theproofcount>0 \pushQED{\whiteged} \else \pushQED{\blackged} \fi%
 \refstepcounter{proofcount}
 \normalfont 
 \trivlist
 \item[\hskip\labelsep
       \itshape
   {\bf\em #1}]\ignorespaces
}{%
 \addtocounter{proofcount}{-1}
 \popQED\endtrivlist
}
%
%
% New definition of square root:
% it renames \sqrt as \oldsqrt
\let\oldsqrt\sqrt
% it defines the new \sqrt in terms of the old one
\def\sqrt{\mathpalette\DHLhksqrt}
\def\DHLhksqrt#1#2{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1\oldsqrt{#2\,}$}\dimen0=\ht0
\advance\dimen0-0.2\ht0
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height\ht0 depth -\dimen0}%
{\box0\lower0.4pt\box2}}
%
% My caption style
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \captionnamefont{\scshape} 
    \changecaptionwidth
    \captionwidth{0.9\linewidth}
    \captiondelim{.\:} 
    \indentcaption{0.75cm}
    \captionstyle[\centering]{}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \caption{#2}\else \caption[#1]{#2}
}
%
% My subcaption style
\newcommand{\mysubcaption}[2][\@empty]{
    \subcaptionsize{\small}
    \hangsubcaption
    \subcaptionlabelfont{\rmfamily}
    \sidecapstyle{\raggedright}
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{10pt}
    \ifx \@empty#1 \subcaption{#2}\else \subcaption[#1]{#2}
}
%
%An initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{
        \color{gray}
            {\textsc{#1}}}{}}
%
% Theorem styles used in my thesis
%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lemma}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{resu}{Result}[chapter]
%
% Hyphenation for some words
%
\hyphenation{res-pec-tively}
\hyphenation{mono-ti-ca-lly}
\hyphenation{hypo-the-sis}
\hyphenation{para-me-ters}
\hyphenation{sol-va-bi-li-ty}
%
%
\begin{document}
% -----------------------------------------------------------Pages
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\input{frontmatter/title}

%
\input{frontmatter/abstract}

%
\input{frontmatter/dedication}

%
\input{frontmatter/declaration}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{thesisbiblio}

%
% Add index
%\printindex
%   
\end{document}
```

Comment: abstract.tex has nothing to include a line at the top

Comment: Please make an MWE (a minimum working environment) which allows to reproduce your case. (should not be with the actual text. (When trying to remove irrelevant parts, I used to find out, why the problem occurs)

Comment: *Excellent template, no worries, everything predefined* <- Stuff like that, always wrong. Either the stuff that i supposed to be is hidden in a class or package file, or if not, it is rubbish and about to fail. Just if you were looking for a *nice template*.

Comment: Is it possible, that this is the line separating the header from the main type area?

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If that what we see really is the hearule, you can remove it by commenting out the  line starting with `\makeheadrule`.

Comment: The line shown probably is the headrule, but i cannot be sure and so will not post an answer. The code example is huge, but not compilable. There was never any feedback, i vtc as unclear.